# EF LINQ Count by Grouped field

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following data schema:

[image: SQL Server data diagram]

With the following LINQ query:

```cs
var profiles = (
    from p in context.BusinessProfiles
    join u in context.Users on p.UserId equals u.Id
    join addr in context.BusinessAddress on p.ProfileId equals addr.ProfileId into addrj
    from addr in addrj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join pa in context.BusinessProfileActivities on p.ProfileId equals pa.ProfileId into paj
    from paIfNull in paj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where p.ProfileId >= 137 && p.ProfileId <= 139
    group new { p, u, addr, paIfNull } 
        by new {
            p.ProfileId,
            p.CompanyName,
            p.Email,
            UserEmail = u.Email,
            addr.City, addr.Region,
            addr.Country,
            ActivityProfileId = paIfNull.ProfileId } 
        into pg
    select new {
        pg.Key.ProfileId,
        pg.Key.CompanyName,
        Email = pg.Key.Email ?? pg.Key.UserEmail,
        pg.Key.City,
        pg.Key.Region,
        pg.Key.Country,
        MatchingActivities = pg.Key.ActivityProfileId > 0 ? pg.Count() : 0
    } into result
    orderby result.MatchingActivities descending
    select result
);
```

Which results with:

[image: Linq results]

This result is corrent (`ProfileId` `137` has 0 activities, `138` has 1 and `139` has 2), but it produces the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [b].[ProfileId], [b].[CompanyName], COALESCE([b].[Email], [a].[Email]) AS [Email], [b0].[City], [b0].[Region], [b0].[Country], 
    CASE WHEN [b1].[ProfileId] > CAST(0 AS bigint) THEN COUNT(*)
    ELSE 0
END AS [MatchingActivities]
FROM [BusinessProfiles] AS [b]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [b].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [BusinessAddress] AS [b0] ON [b].[ProfileId] = [b0].[ProfileId]
LEFT JOIN [BusinessProfileActivities] AS [b1] ON [b].[ProfileId] = [b1].[ProfileId]
WHERE ([b].[ProfileId] >= CAST(137 AS bigint)) AND ([b].[ProfileId] <= CAST(139 AS bigint))
GROUP BY [b].[ProfileId], [b].[CompanyName], [b].[Email], [a].[Email], [b0].[City], [b0].[Region], [b0].[Country], [b1].[ProfileId]
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN [b1].[ProfileId] > CAST(0 AS bigint) THEN COUNT(*)
    ELSE 0
END DESC
```

In SQL, I can avoid both `CASE WHEN` if I use `COUNT([b1].[ProfileId])` like this:

```sql
SELECT [b].[ProfileId], [b].[CompanyName], COALESCE([b].[Email], [a].[Email]) AS [Email], [b0].[City], [b0].[Region], [b0].[Country], 
    COUNT([b1].[ProfileId]) AS [MatchingActivities]
FROM [BusinessProfiles] AS [b]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [b].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [BusinessAddress] AS [b0] ON [b].[ProfileId] = [b0].[ProfileId]
LEFT JOIN [BusinessProfileActivities] AS [b1] ON [b].[ProfileId] = [b1].[ProfileId]
WHERE ([b].[ProfileId] >= CAST(137 AS bigint)) AND ([b].[ProfileId] <= CAST(139 AS bigint))
GROUP BY [b].[ProfileId], [b].[CompanyName], [b].[Email], [a].[Email], [b0].[City], [b0].[Region], [b0].[Country], [b1].[ProfileId]
ORDER BY [MatchingActivities] DESC
```

**My question is, how can I count by grouped `ActivityProfileId = paIfNull.ProfileId` using LINQ and get EF to generate the above SQL?**

I have tried so many variations resulting mostly in EF to SQL errors.

```csharp
MatchingActivities = pg.Count(t => t.ActivityProfileId!= 0)
```

```csharp
MatchingActivities = pg.Select(t => t.paIfNull.ProfileId).Distinct().Count(),
```

```csharp
MatchingActivities = pg.Count(t => t.paIfNull != null),
```

All result in errors like `System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression ... could not be translated.` or getting `MatchingActivities` as `1` instead of `0`.

Related Q/A:

[LINQ Count returning 1 instead of zero for an empty group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635523/linq-count-returning-1-instead-of-zero-for-an-empty-group)

[Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

[How to write left join, group by and average in c# entity framework Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580646/how-to-write-left-join-group-by-and-average-in-c-sharp-entity-framework-linq)

Answer (score 1):

In short you can't! `EF Core` still doesn't support that.

See this:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17376

And also See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878332/9212040